# What mechanism allows dehumidifiers to remove more humidity than air conditioning?

Tags: humidity

So an air conditioner has a condenser and evaporator on different sides of the window, and produces a lot of condensation as a byproduct.

A dehumidifier pulls air onto cold coils, separating water out, and reheating the air. Dehumidifier actually makes the room hotter because it concerts latent heat into sensible heat.

I don't understand how these two devices have different water volume output.

Also the humidifiers work for areas the size of 3500 and 5000 square feet, while using only 300-500 watts, meanwhile air conditioners use 600 watt units for a 400 square foot room.

How are dehumidifiers using less energy? How are they removing more water with less power?

What happens if you take the dehumidifier and move the condenser outdoors, does it become ac, and magically make less condensate?

Comment: I've never seen a stand-alone dehumidifier that would work on a 5000 square foot house (which is a BIG house). And my AC unit sure dumps a lot of water. I don't think your assumptions are correct.

Comment: Uh, go searching for a 50 pint humidifier. They got some crazy numbers.

Comment: Re, "Dehumidifier actually makes the room hotter because it concerts latent heat into sensible heat." Not sure what that means, but _my_ dehumidifier consumes a fair amount of electrical _power,_ and all that power has no other place to go except out the exhaust port as heat.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, large heat engines are more mechanically efficient (higher ratio of mechanical work done to electrical energy consumed), and this effect can dwarf any advantages in thermodynamic coefficient of performance (ratio of heat transfer across the boundary to mechanical work done on the system). Ten small heat engines may draw 5 times as much power as one large heat engine that moves 10 times the heat of each small heat engine, simply because of the engineering constraints. I suspect that this is the real cause of the difference you are measuring. Insofar as that is the case, this question would belong on Engineering SE, not Physics SE.

However, holding all engineering constraints equal, we would still find that a given unit removes more water from the air when used as a dehumidifier than when used as an air conditioner. Suppose we take the window AC unit out of the window and put it in the middle of the room with a drip pan to collect water,  we hold the temperature and humidity of the room constant, we set the AC unit to maximum power, and we assume that nothing freezes or accumulates, so that water removed from the air is proportional to heat moved from one side of the unit to the other.

Note: coefficient of performance (desired effect divided by input work) is not efficiency (desired effect divided by total energy into the system). Since the efficiency includes the heat into the system from the source end of the unit, not just the energy we provide to the unit through the power plug, it doesn't contain information that's useful to us.

Maximal heat pump coefficient of performance is a factor of relative temperature.

For thermodynamic work (cooling) $Q$, mechanical work (product of time, power consumption, and mechanical efficiency) $W$, source temperature $T_C$, heat sink temperature $T_H$ reversed Carnot engine coefficient of performance is:

$\frac{Q}W \lt \frac{T_C}{T_H - T_C}$

As $T_C \to T_H$ the coefficient of performance goes to infinity: that is, any amount of work done can move an unlimited amount of heat, limited only by entropy gains of the thermodynamic system, mechanical inefficiency in the hardware, and heat lost to electrical resistance in the wires. All we need to do is compress the air on one side the tiniest bit and it will be at a higher temperature, causing heat to flow across the boundary.

So, for a given machine, we should expect more heat moved from the input to output end of the machine and hence more water removed from the air, per unit electrical energy input, when the output end is the same temperature as the input end. The AC unit in the window should drip less water into its drip pan than the AC unit in the middle of the living room, holding all else constant, unless it's as cold or colder outside than it is inside.

Comment: I see. This sort of creates a open problem that wasn't solved. Latent heat absorption by the ac will remove performance of sensible heat removal. So the ac busy removing humidity will cool less. If a humidifier can remove latent heat with less energy, it's weird there is no hybrid ac units that would remove high levels of humidity.
still having trouble understanding why the indoor ac would drip more. is it because the temperature difference with the outside is too high?

Comment: i know ACs move an insane amount of BTUs when they are first turned on when there is no temperature delta, they create the temperature delta fast, but the bigger the delta, the less efficient they become and more power they use. So it's like the indoor humidifier sees latent heat as regular heat, and since the hot and cold side are together, it's like it's permanently, always, at lowest temperature delta, and maximum efficiency. So they use 3x less power.

Answer (score 0):

The dehumidifier uses its own waste heat to reheat the airflow after chilling it first to condense the water out of it- while an air conditioner dumps that heat outside the room being cooled.